# Cannot find link to my user page on DBA Stack Exchange

Tags: support, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using Internet Explorer 8 and I have some accounts on Stack Exchange. On [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) on top of the page there are some drop down boxes and the links to my account and to chat, meta, about and faq  and also a field for entering words to search for.

On most of the other Stack Exchange pages where I have an account, e.g. on [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), I can only see the Stack Exchange drop down list and the search field but nothing more. Especially I can't see the link to my account.

What can I do to enable the missing links?

**Edit**:

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure you're signed in when you are looking at those other sites? And can you post a screenshot?

Comment: i searched my user in the userspage and edited my profile without any login. therefore it seems that i am already logged in.

Comment: @Anna Lear: I am sure that i am logged in. I write all my posts without further login.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with Internet Explorer 9 running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're viewing that particular site with Compatibility Mode enabled, which causes issues by bumping things down to near-IE 7 levels (IE 7 itself is [unsupported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)). Disable it by clicking the broken document icon in the URL bar.

For what it's worth though, the problem is caused by the `text-indent: -999em` on `.profile-triangle` which causes IE to apply some crazy negative offset that prevents the contents of the `#hlinks` container from being visible on-screen. I don't have a good explanation for that behaviour, so I'll just shrug and mutter "Old IE, meh" instead.

Comment: thank you, this works

Comment: Nice catch. Must confess, I haven't used IE enough in recent history to remember how this stuff works...